# how to get Video Id in Android application

Tags: android, video-thumbnails

I am doing project for Multimedia application in android technology.

First I will describe the process. whenever I click my installed apk it will show entire videos files from SD card, then by clicking any of the video file it will shows the video description with video thumbnails images. then by clicking thumbnail image it will play the video through my own multimedia application.

I finalized all the concept except to view the videos in thumbnails format. I will show the source-code which i used to view the thumbnail.

```
Bitmap curThumb = MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.getThumbnail(crThumb, imageID, MediaStore.Video.Thumbnails.MICRO_KIND, options);
```

Here imageID is an integer, but I declared `getIntent().getStringExtra` for imageID in String varaible.

can any one guide me how to access the thumbnail `ImageView` for video files?